# Why use context.save and context.restore()?

Tags: javascript, html

Why is it need to use context.save and context.restore() in any Javascript that is drawing lines to a canvas?

```
         this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
```

I am certain that it has to do with this line of code this.canvas.getContext("2d"); and canvas was defined above.

```
         this.canvas = document.getElementById(config.canvasId);
```

Code:

```
         BarChart.prototype.drawGridlines = function(){
            var context = this.context;
            context.save();
            context.strokeStyle = this.gridColor;
            context.lineWidth = 2;

            // draw y axis grid lines
            for (var n = 0; n < this.numGridLines; n++) {
                var y = (n * this.height / this.numGridLines) + this.y;
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(this.x, y);
                context.lineTo(this.x + this.width, y);
                context.stroke();
            }
            context.restore();
         };
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation of those methods? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_graphics_with_canvas#Graphics_State , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#save()

Comment: Excellent explanation can be found [here](http://html5.litten.com/understanding-save-and-restore-for-the-canvas-context/) (sorry, I don't feel like writing a summary here as an answer today ;))

Answer (score 0):

context.save() saves the current state of the context (strokeStyle, lineWidth, etc...) then your code will change those values.  At the end of your code you call context.restore() which will restore the previous values that your code has changed.

This way you don't need to manually restore everything you changed and your code will not affect other code on the page that has previously modified these values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. context.save and context.restore are often used for efficient texture translation and rotation, hence show up in many examples.

Save stores your position, angle and various other canvas states. Then you can move to the position/angle you want to draw your image. Restore can then snap your co-ord grid back to the save point. Much easier than rotating points in space mathematically, and the only way to rotate images i know of with canvas 2d context mode.

If your doing simple drawing of boxes, lines or unrotated images then don't bother.